# Can we define radius value for each heatmap data?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have a data that has monetary values in it and I am asked to prepare a heatmap out of it. I am trying to define different weight options for the data but it is hardly seen on the map when it is zoomed.
I want to be able to see the radius difference even when I'm all the way zoomed on the map. Can we achieve this?

Can we put any radius values in the data?

```
latLng = {
     location: new google.maps.LatLng(results[i].LATITUDE.replace(',', '.'), results[i].LONGITUDE.replace(',', '.')),
     weight: .4
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define a radius value for each data point. The data can be either a `LatLng` object or a `WeightedLocation` object. See the [heatmap reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/visualization).

You can set a radius to the heatmap itself though, like this:

```
var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: heatMapData,
    radius:40
});
```

You can test changing the radius in this full [working example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap).

To better differentiate data points, besides setting a radius, and using weights for data points, you can also dissipate the heatmap on zoom by setting the dissipating parameter, and modify opacity and gradient. I recommend going through [Google's documentation on heatmaps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer) for more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I ended up with setting the maxIntensity to 100 and giving 0.5 - 1 etc. values for the datas that are not very important for the heatmap but still there. Thanks for the answer @evan :)

Comment: Thank you, glad to hear! :)